# How to add different series data for each categories in Stacked Column chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this Stacked Column Chart I want to add different series for different categories in x axis. For example, in the category of apple i want to show aaa=1,bbb=2,ccc=3 and for the category of Oranges i want to show like eee=5,fff=4,ggg=1 and so on.Is it possible?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `x` data values, for example as the first elements in arrays:

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [
        [0, 5],
        [1, 3]
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 2]
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [
        [0, 3],
        [2, 4]
    ]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nh1toe8g/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. Nice to see you again :) Thanks for the help, I find my solution from your API reference :)